# Php $bom not working with mode a/a+ in fopen

Tags: php, fopen, byte-order-mark

I want to write on a .csv file with UTF-8 characters and I'm using $bom.

This is working fine with **fopen** and mode c/c+, r/r+ or w/w+ but not with mode a/a+. It's important for me to add data at the end of the file and not at the beginning. With this mode a/a+ the special characters are not recognized. I am unable to understand the root cause of this issue.

Below is the code:

```
$fp = fopen("my_file.csv", "a+");
fputs($fp, $bom = ( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ) );
fputcsv($fp, array("col1","col2","col3"), ";");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Works fine on my PHP (5.6.30).  Verify your permissions on the file and the directory containing it, for the user running apache maybe?  Ah and verify the status of the fopen, maybe it failed for some reason (permissions again).

Comment: Thank you Nic3500, I'll check the permissions. Are the permissions different regarding to the mode used in fopen? Why is it working for mode "w" and not "a"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put the Unicode [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) anywhere you want, it has to be on top of the file:

> BOM use is optional, and, if used, **should appear at the start of the text stream**.

Comment: Hi, if you run his code, it will write it anywhere in the file.  Maybe that is his problem after all...

Comment: @Nic3500 Yep. Took me a while to figure out too :) Other modes work because they truncate the file.